# How to write a PHP button to select row from database and run python code

Tags: php, mysql, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I have written a python script for a set of musical stairs using a raspberry pi and some motion sensors which act as a switch, and upon being passed they will make a noise. In my MySQL database I have two different settings - piano or drum, and depending on which is selected, a different block of code will run.

I am wondering is it possible to make a PHP button to select from the database and then cause the python block to run depending on which PHP button is pressed?

I have tried a simple SQL statement and connecting with the database in PHP but it hasn't done anything so far.

This is for a Raspberry Pi 3 running Python2.7 (I know I should upgrade but this is the latest version that connects with mariadb), PHP and Apache 2.

````
 #!/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages
import mysql.connector as mariadb # connect to mysql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # GPIO
import pygame.mixer # To make sound
pygame.mixer.init()
```Connect to database
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='*****', database='stairs')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

```GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

```Motion sensor setup
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE key_ = 'currentInstrument'")
    settings = cursor.fetchall()

   for id in settings:
        input_state = GPIO.input(4)
        if input_state == False:
            if(id==1):
                print('GPIO4 Piano')
                C1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
                C1.play()

            if(id==2):
                print('GPIO4 Drum')
                drum1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drum c1.wav")
                drum1.play()

        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
        if input_state == False:   
            if(id==1):
                print('GPIO17 Piano')
                D = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/D.wav")
                D.play()

            if(id==2):
                print('GPIO17 Drum')
                drum2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drum d.wav")
                drum2.play()
````

The expected output should be that when a PHP button is pressed it should select either 1 or 2 from the database which should then in turn choose what instrument is played

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (assuming the php button is in some web page):

HTML/PHP page:
RUN

The button is related to php file "run.php", if pressed the page is redirected to "run.php".

Inside "run.php" launch the python script:

```
    <?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('pathto/script.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

This will run the python script from web page